# How to switch a serial images in Android Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I reach an Android issue and need your helps.

I need to display a serial of images in an Activity, and:

1. I can switch the images one by one with gesture.
2. Images are not fixed in Resource. Since they are from internet, I cannot add them in advance.
3. I can handle the response in clicking the "current image".

Mmm...So far I don't have other ideas. Search in the webs, some people are using Gallery, and others said Gallery was out of date, not recommended. And some people used fragment, but I need only display pictures. 
I hope to a quick and easy way, any help is appreciated in advance.

As below:

http://s3.amazonaws.com/img.tnt/ba47668/c487_l.jpg

Comment: Implement ViewPager or buy the looks of the image you've linked a HorizontalScrollView.

Comment: Refer this http://androidopentutorials.com/android-image-slideshow-using-viewpager/